# Covariance matrix system identification matlab

Tags: matlab, covariance, levenberg-marquardt

We're doing a system identification starting from a given response and we want to match it to our mathematical system, obtaining some parameters that are not known. We are using the PEM algorithm built in in MATLAB, with the option set to Levenberg-Marquardt.

Everything goes according to plan, and we obtain the parameters we needed with a 94% match with the given curve.

The issue is that when we pull the covariance matrix associated to those parameters, all the entries are way bigger than expected. For example, the first parameter is in the order or `1e-3` and its variance is something like `1e9`...that doesn't seem correct.

Does someone know why it is happening?

Thanks in advance to whoever will answer, I'll post a slice of the code related to the question.

```
opt2 = greyestOptions('InitialState', 'zero',...
                      'SearchMethod', 'lm');

opt2.SearchOption.Tolerance = 0.001;
opt2.SearchOption.MaxIter   = 400;

sys           = pem(data, idsys, opt2);
[x_opt, t, x] = lsim(sys, u, t);
```

Comment: This would be for sure driven by the data. First of all, normalize your data, in order all are in the (0,1) range. Then repeat your identification. I could assure you the variances will get regularized....

Comment: By normalizing the data you are referring to the measurements I have and that i want to match with my system or the characteristic matrix of the system?

Comment: Because I found out that the characteristic matrix at issue is badly conditioned and I fear thats the reason everything is going crazy

Comment: Yeah... Check the data units and its variability.....

Comment: Actually the data were refined in order to prevent that from happening, like the x ones are between 0 and 15 with scaling like a step while the y is between 0 and 4 with fixed step, so I wouldn't know,

Comment: Do you think that could be related to the system being y=Ax and A being really badly conditioned?

Comment: And the variability of the data. When you make estimate with low variable data, you get illconditioning. It is a requirement for all SI algorithms to have variability. Thats why i asked you about normalization, so you can have a clear sight of what you are having...